# Array index limit in C

Tags: c, arrays

On Linux, with 16 GB of RAM, why would the following segfault:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 44000

int main(void) {
    long width = N*2 - 1;
    int * c = (int *) calloc(width*N, sizeof(int));
    c[N/2] = 1;
    return 0;
}
```

According to GDB the problem is from c[N/2] = 1 , but what is the reason?

Comment: Are you compiling/running on a 64 bit arcitecture ?

Comment: Even on linux 64, user limit settings and what-not can get into the way. I remember the company i worked for had 32GB ram machines, and i was only allowed to take 4GB for one user process.

Comment: But are you sure you're using the 64-bit compiler? If you print out `sizeof(long)`, what is it?

Comment: @pavel: printf("%ld\n", sizeof(long)); = 8

Comment: Have you possibly run firefox, movie players and openoffice in the background, too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're allocating around 14-15 GB memory, and for whatever reason the allocator cannot
give you that much at the moment- thus `calloc` returns NULL and you segfault as you're dereferencing a NULL pointer.

Check if calloc returns NULL.

That's assuming you're compiling a 64-bit program under a 64-bit Linux. If you're doing something else - you might overflow the calculation to the first argument to `calloc` if a long is not 64 bits on your system.

For example, try

```
#include    <stdlib.h>
#include    <stdio.h>

#define N    44000L

int main(void)
{
    size_t width = N * 2 - 1;
    printf("Longs are %lu bytes. About to allocate %lu bytes\n",
           sizeof(long), width * N * sizeof(int));
    int *c = calloc(width * N, sizeof(int));
    if (c == NULL) {
        perror("calloc");
        return 1;
    }
    c[N / 2] = 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it does return null, is there a way to get around that?

Answer (score 6):

It's probably because the return value of calloc was NULL.

The amount of physical RAM in your box does not directly correlate to how much memory you can allocate with calloc/malloc/realloc.  That is more directly determined by the remaining amount of Virtual Memory available to your process.

Comment: Based on my calculations (assuming `int` is 4 bytes) you're asking the OS for ~14GB of contiguous space, which I could see failing in this case.

Comment: 2.6GB, actually, but still enough to fail.

Comment: I got 14.4241GB in my calculations (assuming 4bytes int too).

Comment: I didn't calculate, I coded. :)  `printf("%lu\n", (width*N) * sizeof(int));` yielded 2602922112.

Comment: But, compiled for 64 bit, it is 15487824000 -- 14.4GB, thus begging the question of why Linux's calloc() can't return a 14GB chunk o' memory.

Comment: @bbum, you're doing this on a 32-bit platform, where `unsigned long` is 32-bit. It simply overflowed. The correct number is indeed ~14Gb.

Comment: You missed that he is multiplying by N twice;  once in calculating width and again in the calloc call.

Comment: @Will, it's `(44000 * 2 - 1) * 44000 * 4`.

Comment: Yup-- I screwed up the overflow. Bad coder, no coffee. Wait. More coffee.

Comment: wow I really can't read apparently - I read width*N as width.  /bonk-self

Answer (score 6):

Your calculation overflows the range of a 32-bit signed integer, which is what "long" may be. You should use size_t instead of long.  This is guaranteed to be able to hold the size of the largest memory block that your system can allocate.

Comment: The largest memory block a system can allocate is never a round power of 2 number.  Shared memory, library mappings, file mappings, runtime metadata, etc... will always occupy some subset of allocations.

Comment: Read my answer. I did not say "The system is able to allocate blocks of any size representable in a size_t". I said "size_t can represent any size block that the system is able to allocate." These are quite different statements.

Comment: In particular I am suggesting that his program is crashing not because he asked for too much RAM but because he inadvertently passed a negative number as the argument to calloc.

Comment: Regardless of wether there's shared libs occupying the space, the size will eventually be a power of 2. If he's on a 32 bit linux he will 1. overflow the argument to calloc 2. run out of address space - calloc will fail even if it didn't overflow

Comment: On 64-bit Linux (and all other Unices), GCC follows the LP64 model - that is, both pointers and `long` are 64-bit. See http://gcc.fyxm.net/summit/2003/Porting%20to%2064%20bit.pdf

Comment: @Pavel: and size_t, which is the parameter to calloc.

Comment: Edited the question just so I could remove my spastic monkey down vote.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking for 2.6 GB of RAM (no, you aren't -- you are asking for 14 GB on 64 bit... 2.6 GB overflowed cutoff calculation on 32 bit).  Apparently, Linux's heap is utilized enough that `calloc()` can't allocate that much at once.

This works fine on Mac OS X (both 32 and 64 bit) -- but just barely (and would likely fail on a different system with a different [dyld](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html) shared cache and frameworks).

And, of course, it should work dandy under 64 bit on any system (even the 32 bit version with the bad calculation worked, but only coincidentally).

One more detail;  in a "real world app", the largest contiguous allocation will be vastly reduced as the complexity and/or running time of the application increases. The more of the heap that is used, the less contiguous space there is to allocate.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to change the #define to:

```
#define N    44000L
```

just to make sure the math is being done at long resolution. You may be generating a negative number for the `calloc`.

`Calloc` may be failing and returning null which would cause the problem.

Comment: That won't make any difference unless int is 16 bit, which seems unlikely. 44000*2-1 fits in 32 bit int, then is assigned to a long "width", then width*N is calculated in long since that's the larger type, then calloc will use size_t internally.

Answer (score 1):

Create a 14 GB file, and memory map it.

Answer (score 1):

Dollars to donuts `calloc()` returned NULL because it couldn't satisfy the request, so attempting to deference c caused the segfault.  You should *always* check the result of `*alloc()` to make sure it isn't NULL.